# Multiple container views VS multiple view controllers linked to a single container View

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

[image]

I have a view with following configuration. by clicking a button the respective container view should move to the main screen with animation. If I am in portrait or landscape mode(only one of those) this works well but if I try to rotate iphone this does not work.

```
- (IBAction)button2Pressed:(UIButton *)button {
if(previousButton != button){
    if([previousButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"1"])
        [self viewLoadedIntoContainer:-self.container1.frame.size.width];
    else if([previousButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"3"])
        [self viewLoadedIntoContainer:self.container1.frame.size.width];
    else
        [self viewLoadedIntoContainer:self.container1.frame.size.width*2];
    previousButton = button;
    [self animateLabel:self.button2Outlet.frame.origin.x];
    indexCount=1;
}}

- (IBAction)button1Pressed:(UIButton *)button {
if(previousButton != button){
    if([previousButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"2"])
        [self viewLoadedIntoContainer:self.container1.frame.size.width];
    else if([previousButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"3"])
        [self viewLoadedIntoContainer:self.container1.frame.size.width*2];
    else
        [self viewLoadedIntoContainer:self.container1.frame.size.width*3];

    previousButton = button;

    [self animateLabel:self.button1Outlet.frame.origin.x];
    indexCount=0;
}}

- (IBAction)button3Pressed:(UIButton *)button {
if(previousButton != button){
    if([previousButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"1"])
       [self viewLoadedIntoContainer:-self.container1.frame.size.width*2];
    else if([previousButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"2"])
        [self viewLoadedIntoContainer:-self.container1.frame.size.width];
    else
       [self viewLoadedIntoContainer:self.container1.frame.size.width];
    previousButton = button;

    [self animateLabel:self.button3Outlet.frame.origin.x];
    indexCount=2;
}}

- (IBAction)button4Pressed:(UIButton *)button {
if(previousButton != button){
    if([previousButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"3"])
        [self viewLoadedIntoContainer:-self.container1.frame.size.width];
    else if([previousButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"2"])
        [self viewLoadedIntoContainer:-self.container1.frame.size.width*2];
    else
        [self viewLoadedIntoContainer:-self.container1.frame.size.width*3];
    previousButton = button;
    [self animateLabel:self.button4Outlet.frame.origin.x];
    indexCount=3;
}}

-(void)viewLoadedIntoContainer:(CGFloat)x{
 __weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{

    weakSelf.container1.layer.position = CGPointMake(weakSelf.container1.layer.position.x+(x), weakSelf.container1.layer.position.y);
    weakSelf.container2.layer.position = CGPointMake(weakSelf.container2.layer.position.x+(x), weakSelf.container2.layer.position.y);
    weakSelf.container3.layer.position = CGPointMake(weakSelf.container3.layer.position.x+(x), weakSelf.container3.layer.position.y);
    weakSelf.container4.layer.position = CGPointMake(weakSelf.container4.layer.position.x+(x), weakSelf.container4.layer.position.y);
    //[weakSelf.container1 setFrame:CGRectMake(weakSelf.container1.frame.origin.x+(x), weakSelf.container1.frame.origin.y, weakSelf.container1.frame.size.width, weakSelf.container1.frame.size.height)];

    //[weakSelf.container2 setFrame:CGRectMake(weakSelf.container2.frame.origin.x+(x), weakSelf.container2.frame.origin.y, weakSelf.container2.frame.size.width, weakSelf.container2.frame.size.height)];

    //[weakSelf.container3 setFrame:CGRectMake(weakSelf.container3.frame.origin.x+(x), weakSelf.container3.frame.origin.y, weakSelf.container3.frame.size.width, weakSelf.container3.frame.size.height)];

    //[weakSelf.container4 setFrame:CGRectMake(weakSelf.container4.frame.origin.x+(x), weakSelf.container4.frame.origin.y, weakSelf.container4.frame.size.width, weakSelf.container4.frame.size.height)];

}completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    //[weakSelf.container1 layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

}

I am using 4 container views. Should I use 4 container views which are of same height and width and lies on top of each other. Or should I use 4 view controller which are linked to single container view using custom segue?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on exactly on the specifics of what each view/view controller does.

But generally speaking; I usually make each "screen" (full frame view) its own UIViewController. I usually make subviews of a screen UIViews.

Comment: I have edited my question. Can you see what's wrong I am doing here.